# PHP add dynamically row into an existing HTML table

Tags: php, html, html-table

Within a wordpress plugin, I have a PHP function which transform **$file_name** (a CSV file) into a table.

```
function displayAsTable($file_name)
{
echo '<table>';     
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
$f = fopen($file_name, "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f,0,",")) !== false) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="addressXX" value="'.$line[2].'" name=""/></td>';
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($cell) . '</td>';
        }
        echo '<tr>';
}
fclose($f);
echo '</table>';
}
```

The problem is that I would like to add the new ROWS and COLUMNS into an existing TABLE within the same page! How could I do that easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove "echo <table>" and "echo </table>" and insert that function inside the existing table element. That should solve the problem because it will simply create new rows in addition to existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would change this function to:

```
function displayAsTable($file_name,$newTable = TRUE)
{
    if($newTable){ echo '<table>'; }
    //rest of code without last echo
    if($newTable){ echo '</table>'; }
}
```

And call it like: `displayAsTable('rowstoappend.csv',false);`